# How do I add a link to my CSS background?

Tags: html, css, background, hyperlink

I am having trouble with add a link to my css background. I know it is not possible but I am wondering how I would add it through my html. this is my css

```
`.home-featured.wall {
padding: 20px 0;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0) url(images/bg-pattern-black.png);
background-image: url(http://viralcentro.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/NBA-ad-Viral-Centro.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
position: relative;
text-shadow: none;
height: 730px;`
```

My site is http://viralcentro.com/
and the background I am trying to add a link to is the basketball one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get an SSL error when trying to follow your link.You can put a background image on a link, but you can't make a bg image itself clickable. Background images are just decorations, rather than an element in your page structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm well why don't you try making the image local and putting it in a folder with your other images on your server. It may not be working because its taking to long to process the image. Also try using quotes when you link to images.

```
.home-featured.wall {
padding: 20px 0;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0) url('images/bg-pattern-black.png');
background-image: url('dir_imgs/NBA-ad-Viral-Centro.png'); /* replace dir_imgs with your     folder name*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
position: relative;
text-shadow: none;
height: 730px;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one way I could think of this. It's not the best way, but it should do the trick. Here it goes.

HTML:

```
<div id="backgroundpic">
        <img src="http://viralcentro.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/NBA-ad-Viral-Centro.png" onclick="redirect()" alt="something or other">
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
            function redirect() {
                window.open(where_ever_you_want_it_to_go)
            }
        </script>
```

CSS:

```
# backgroundpic {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

If you're not too comfortable with JavaScript, it's fine, but it might be easier.